# Rails 3 AR: Save and update methods do not save attributes changed in database but not object in memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Consider this scenario:

1. butterfly = Butterfly.create(:color='blue')
2. Butterfly.update_all(:color='red')

At this point, as expected, butterfly (in memory) is blue while the corresponding database object is red. Now try to update the database entry

1. butterfly.update_attributes(:size=>'big')

The result is that the size attribute is updated but the color is not. We're left with a situation where, even after a successful save or update_attributes, the database does not match the object in memory. In fact, even `butterfly.update_attribute(:color, 'blue')` is not enough to force a change in the database! The only way I see to force is the change is by first updating the attribute to something else (`butterfly.update_attribute(:color,'anything')`) and then changing it back to the original value.

Is this the way things are supposed to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort-of.

`Model.update_all` issues an update query directly to the underlying database; it doesn't update any instances you already have in memory. Similarly, `instance.update_attributes` only updates—it doesn't re-fetch from the database, as it assumes that the instance has the most up-to-date attribute values already.

This *usually* works in Rails, instances are generally short-lived: they only exist within the scope of the request, and in most cases, they're being operated on directly.

In the situation you describe above, you need an extra step—`Model#reload` will do what you want:

```
# create our instance
@butterfly = Butterfly.create(color: 'blue') # => #<Butterfly id: 100, color: 'blue'>

Butterfly.update_all(color: 'red')

# We now have a mis-match between our instance and our database. Our instance 
# is still blue, but the database says it should be red. Reloading it...

@butterfly.reload # => #<Butterfly id: 100, color: 'red'>

# And we can now re-update our butterfly
@butterfly.update_attributes(size: 'big') # => #<Butterfly id: 100, color: 'red', size: 'big'>
```

If you're using `update_all`, it's a good idea to see if it's possible to structure your code so that it occurs *before* you load instances.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's what I figured was happening, but it doesn't strike me as the way things ought to be. In my case, I don't want to keep the value in the database, I want to keep the one in the model, so reload does not help.

In fact, I stumbled onto this because I wanted to do this: before save, if butterfly is marked as "the_best", clear "the_best" from all other butterflies in the db. That seemed a simple way to ensure only one butterfly has "the_best" attribute. I can, instead, use update_all(:the_best=>false, "id != #{self.id}"), but it just seems it ought not be necessary.

Comment: I guess the basic question is, why doesn't "save" or at least an explicit "update_attribute" just save to the database as one might expect, rather than saving only attributes that have not been changed in the object in memory?

Comment: If your rule is that only one Butterfly can be marked as 'best' at any one time, try this: Butterfly.update_all({ the_best: false }, { the_best: true }); @new_best = Butterfly.find(params[:id]); @new_best.update_attributes(the_best: true);

Comment: As for why, I don't honestly know.